# How can I discard rasters that contain exclusively nodata values when creating tiles?

Tags: qgis, raster, tiles, nodata

I have a large raster that I want chopped up into tiles. To accomplish this, I click "save as" and check off the "Create VRT" box. I set the dimensions of the output tiles to 40 x 40 pixels.

However, approximately half the original large raster has no data. After tiling, many of the resultant tiles are entirely populated with no data values. How can these examples be discarded without manually having to go through hundreds of tiles?